# How to pass filename as an argument passed on launch?

Tags: command-line, bash, xcode

I would like to pass the script's filename to the "Arguments Passed On Launch" found in the Scheme editor under "Run".

I looked at [this Xcode documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/itcaec37c2a6) but did not find an answer.

Currently, I have to manually type the file that I am going to run as SRCROOT only gets you to the directory the file is in. It would be faster if I could hit "Run" for any file in the project directory without having to type the name in.

See the screenshot for what I currently use. Note the filename of the script is "File.py".

Also, let me know what language the arguments passed on launch is. I assumed bash.

[image: arg-screenshot]